# save query result by create_table

Tags: jupyter-notebook, db2

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uUaY.png)

Hello,

I am relatively new to SQL.

I was trying to save my query  result into a table, but I don't know why it does not work.

The select statement does work , I can generate the result of number of crimes, but I don't know why there is an error when I save it to a table

```
%%sql

Create Table crime_count as 

select community_area_number,count(case_number) as crime_number
from Crime
group by community_area_number
order by 2 DESC
```

Comment: In DB2 I think you have to put the SELECT query inside parentheses.

Comment: See https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.5?topic=language-creating-table-using-as

Comment: While possible that the OP is using Db2 for IBM i, LUW seems more likely.. https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=s-create-table#sdx-synid_frag-as-result-table